# Selenium using JUnit

Tags: java, android, selenium, junit

I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to run the following code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Mytest {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Test
public void test() {
driver.manage().window().maximize();
System.out.print("Window maximized");
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.print("Site Open");
driver.quit();
System.out.print("End of Test");
}

}
```

I know that my JUnit.jar is included in the build path and all appropriate Selenium testing jars, and that I can actually create a "new JUnit test" from the Eclipse menu, but the catch might be that I downloaded Eclipse with ADT for android package.  I don't know if this is a problem for JUnit as I have never used it before.  Can anyone see something I don't?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you testing on Firefox or the Android browser? I am just confused cause you added an android tag in this thread. If that is the case, you need the Android Driver. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver now Selendroid http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html

Comment: Post the entirety of the error!

Comment: Please tell us where you in the code you are getting the NullPointerException

Comment: I wish I had an actual error to post.  This is all Eclipse gives me when I hit Run:  An internal error occurred during: "Launching Mytest".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This *exact* code runs perfectly fine for me, from command line and from Eclipse. You must have something else going on. It sounds as if your Eclipse install is buggered up.

Comment: @SiKing I suspect the fact this Eclipse is used for Android developemnt (Juno/mobile developer packages) that is messing it up.

Comment: Download + install a new Eclipse is a no-brainer, and you do **not** even need admin privileges. Try it out!

Comment: Yeah I just confirmed that using the Java EE Eclipse package works like a champ.  It has to be something with the structure of Junit and Android because There are tutorials on how to JUnit test an Android Application.  Maybe trying to use Selenium messes it up.  Either way thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit and Eclipse (Mobile Developer Package) seem to have a different structure than required when trying to use Selenium WebDriver and JUnit.  The solution for me was to install Eclipse J2EE edition and the test ran without issue.